# Can I dissolve IBA from talc powder?

Tags: solubility, extraction

My container of in total 25 grams of rooting powder contains 2.5 mg IBA (Indole-3-butyric acid), which is mixed with talc powder and a tiny bit of chromium(III)oxide. I know talc is not soluble in water or ethanol. But is it possible to add ethanol to dissolve only the IBA? The talc will then remain in my solution. Is this correct?

Comment: *Since IBA is not completely soluble in water, it is typically dissolved in 75% or purer alcohol for use in plant rooting, making a solution of between 10,000 and 50,000 ppm. This alcohol solution is then diluted with distilled water to the desired concentration. IBA is also available as a salt, which is soluble in water.*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole-3-butyric_acid

Comment: The question remains,how much ethanol is needed for the near complete extraction, as it is not the same as dissolving pure compound. Probably the best way would by slow column continuous extraction,similar as elution of ions captured in ion exchaging resin.

Comment: chromium(III)oxide in rooting powder? That is not possible.

Comment: Rooting powder can have fungicides, it is often just not talc, it is advisable not to play around with it.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I checked the SDS, according to that it contains:
- TALC >50%
- Chromium(III)oxide <1%
- IBA <1%
I think the chromium oxide is there to give it a bit of color. Its a nice green powder. I added to 0,8 grams of powder 2ml pure ethanol, shaked it and added it up to 10 ml with destilled water. Let's see if my in-vitro cultivation works...

Comment: It is very strange to find Chromium (III) oxide in rooting powder. I cannot find any role of chromium. Be careful, chromium (III) is toxic and known to cause cancer.

Comment: @M.Farooq Interesting. It is well known about Cr(VI) compounds, but I have never heard it about Cr2O3. It is widely used as a pigment.

Comment: Be aware the talc matrix may play an important role in the kinetics of IBA release, similarly as for medicine pills. In both cases, the way how it is released can be as important as the presence of the active component itself.